# Showing sets are open in a metric space.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $d$ be the usual Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R$ and $f: (\Bbb R, d) \mapsto ([-1,1],d)$ be the map given by $f(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 0, & x=0 \\ \sin \frac 1 x, & x \neq 0 \end{matrix} \right.$.

Let $ -1 <a < b < -1 $. Show that the sets $[-1,a)$, $(a,b)$ and $(b,1]$ are open in $([-1,1],d)$.

Any advice is appreciated on how to approach this problem!

Comment: did you forget a $f$ in your question? Otherwise we do not see why you define it before.

Comment: To show a set is G open you have to show that for every point you can surround it with an open set which is also contained within the set G, so consider simple open intervals ( x,x+eps),(x-eps,x) to surround each point x of the sets you have been given.  The sin(1/x) thingie doesn;'t seem relevant here, is there something missing from the question.

Comment: This is from an exercise in my undergraduate topology book with multiple parts, I apologize. The previous portions of the question ask to show that $f$ is not continuous at $0$ and to show that for an open subset $A$ of $\Bbb R$ $f[A] = [-1,1]$ so the $f$ may just be implied for this portion of the problem. Thank you for pointing that out! @JérémyBlanc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[-1,a) = B_d(-1, a+1)$ when we restrict the metric $d$ to $[-1,1]$.

$(b,1) = B_d(1, 1-b)$ similarly. So they're open balls, hence open.

Similarly for the other ones.